# getting HTML content while using Curl command to download file from github

Tags: github, curl, download, github-api

I am running following command to fetch the content of file from github

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token XXXXXX' 
     -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw'
     -o file.txt
     -L https://github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME/blob/main/file.txt
```

(line breaks only added for readability here)

But the file downloaded or created contains HTML content not content of required file.

Please suggest the command to get same content of file without using raw link.

Comment: so, what does it contain instead? What was the response of the server, including headers? You're sitting on all information here!

Answer (score 0):

You're making a request to the web interface (github.com) and you're getting back an HTML page that contains the data of the file rendered in the web interface.  If you want to download a file programmatically, you should use the [appropriate REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content), which will be at a different URL under the domain `api.github.com`.

In general, you should only make programmatic requests to the API and avoid making requests directly to things under `github.com`.